# "CUDA error at cuCtxCreate: Out of memory" Nothing has been changed since the last time I used blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, error

I'm getting the error in the title even when trying to render just the plain starting cube.  I haven't changed anything in blender since the last time I used it a few months ago when it worked fine.  I have a 1060 6gb and a 770 4gb graphics cards installed.  Won't work in preview or actual render. I started a new blender file; reset factory settings, appended the scene objects to the new file and it worked fine; but if I go into User Preferences and switch to CUDA under the "Cycles Compute Device", it doesn't work again.  Happens on 2.79 and 2.79b  It's faster rendering with CPU than GPU without CUDA enabled. Windows 8.1 Thanks!

-If I uncheck either one of the cards under Cycles Compute device it works.

Comment: so cycles is working with one of the cards, but not both. Are you changing anything about the cards, or just the option for the compute device? Do you have them in SLI?

Comment: LOL, text based context will never be what we need it to be.  Yes i checked that.

Comment: No not SLI and not changing anything